# How to sync content of two files

Tags: linux, unix, synchronization, rsync

I want to sync the content of two files, File1 & File2

Both file having few content common.

- File2 is master file.
- File1 is normal file.

File2:

```
# cat File2

    [default]
host = XXXX

<i>[monitor:///server/dev-01/log/*.log*]</i>

index = main

disabled = false

sourcetype = serverlog
```

File1:

```
# cat File1

    [default]
host = XXXX

<i>[monitor:///server/cat-01/log/*.log*]</i>

index = second

disabled = false

sourcetype = server-logs
```

Required:

```
# cat File2


    [default]
host = XXXX

<i>[monitor:///server/dev-01/log/*.log*]</i>

index = main

disabled = false

sourcetype = serverlog

<i>[monitor:///server/cat-01/log/*.log*]</i>

index = second

disabled = false

sourcetype = server-logs
```

Comment: This doesn't look like syncing the contents of two files. It rather looks like removing some stuff from the top of `File2` and pasting the rest at the end of `File1`. It might help if you could clarify exactly what you need to do...

Comment: This is similar to Union operation we performed in Boolean. Want Union of both files in file2.